# 条件A、条件Bの数値を元に条件Cを除したい

Tags: r, tidyverse

Rでの解析において、条件A、条件Bの数値を元に、条件Cを除するプログラムを書きたいのですが、うまくいきません。

（例）

```
Sample = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Day = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
Value = c(100, 150, 200, 1000, 1050, 1100)
testDF = data.frame(Sample, Day, Value)
testDF
```

上記のようなデータフレームで、Sample A、BのValueの値をそれぞれのDay 0での値で除し、Norm_valueの列を新たに得たいと思っています。
※Norm_value = c(1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.05, 1.1）という列を得られればOK

Mutate関数、ifelseを使って、と考えたのですが、2条件の分岐がうまくいかず、ノウハウをご教示頂けるとありがたいです。どなたか、どうか宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
> library(tidyverse)
> testDF %>% group_by(Sample) %>% mutate(Norm_value = Value / Value[Day==0])

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Sample [2]
  Sample   Day Value Norm_value
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A          0   100       1   
2 A          1   150       1.5 
3 A          2   200       2   
4 B          0  1000       1   
5 B          1  1050       1.05
6 B          2  1100       1.1
```